# Python EOFerror

Tags: python, eoferror

Using python 3.6.1 and getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Computing\CAU\task 3.py", line 72, in <module>
    UniqueWords = pickle.load(MyFile)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

concerning this section of my code:

```
`MyFile = open('SentencesCompression.txt', 'rb')
 UniqueWords = pickle.load(MyFile)
 UniqueWords2 = pickle.load(MyFile)
 WordPositions = pickle.load(MyFile)
 WordPositions2 = pickle.load(MyFile)`
```

As can be seen, I am trying to load back some pickled data.

I hope I have given enough information.

Pastebin of the whole code: https://pastebin.com/4uEA8PcY

Answer (score 0):

You have already read the file you opened and the position pointer is at the end of the file. Pickle cannot load anything because there is nothing to load.

If you really need to load the same file four times, try this:

```
with open('SentencesCompression.txt', 'rb') as MyFile:
  UniqueWords = pickle.load(MyFile)
with open('SentencesCompression.txt', 'rb') as MyFile:
  UniqueWords2 = pickle.load(MyFile)
with open('SentencesCompression.txt', 'rb') as MyFile:
  WordPositions = pickle.load(MyFile)
with open('SentencesCompression.txt', 'rb') as MyFile:
  WordPositions2 = pickle.load(MyFile)
```

Operator `with` is used to ensure that the file is properly closed.

Comment: Compress or Load File 
Answer with the words 
#Compress 
#Load
load
How many sentences did you compress? 
2 or 3
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Computing\CAU\task 3.py", line 74, in <module>
    UniqueWords = pickle.load(MyFile)
EOFError: Ran out of input
>>>The error still persists but thanks for the effort. I think it has something to do with the UniqueWords2 list of the pickle load process

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand how `pickle.load()` is supposed to work.

You probably want something a bit more like:

```
data = pickle.load(MyFile)
UniqueWords = data[0]
UniqueWords2 = data[1]
# ... etc.
```

Assuming that the data you pickled (with `pickle.dump()`) was a list.  If pickled a dictionary then you'd need to unpack the key/value pairs.

The best way to learn out to load pickled (or JSON) data is to read the code that's dumping it out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the error still persist

Comment: If possible post the minimal snippet of code that's creating this *SentencesCompression.txt* pickle file.  Failing that, perform a `data = pickle.load(MyFile)` from the *`>>>`* interpreter prompt and use `dir()` and other introspection features to explore the data structure so you can figure out how to extract the portions of it that you're trying to use.

Comment: Hi, Jim, I was just looking to delete the thread as I had solved the issue. I checked the file that the code was writing to and for some reason it was empty. I moved my script save to another folder and went through the compressing process again. It started to write again and when i ran the code, the error had stopped. Thanks for helping

Comment: It's better to upvote the useful answer so that others encountering similar issues will find this.